# Using merge to track changes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

We're working on doing incremental updates in our database using merge to update last updated values. This works great, however we also track changes when updating the whole table once a day.

Ideally, we would like to track everything that changed during the merge. While previously we would take the old table and the new table and delete them from each other to see what was added & deleted, we would like to get this from the merge.

Here is our condensed merge:

```
MERGE data_warehouse.dbo.data_table AS data_table
USING (
SELECT
   id AS id,
  target_date
  po
FROM #exploded_data_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM #updated_records) AS updates

ON (data_table.id = updateds.id)

WHEN MATCHED AND (data_table.id IN (SELECT id FROM #updated_records) AND (data_table.id <> updated.id OR
  data_table.target_date <> updates.target_date OR
  data_table.po <> updates.po))

  THEN UPDATE SET
  id = updates.id,
  target_date = updates.target_date,
  po = updates.po

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT
(id,
target_date,
po
)
VALUES
(updates.id,
updates.target_date,
updates.po
)
```

Using the merge function, we can get the inserted & deleted items, however, we were wondering if it was possible to get items that were updated.

Our current code takes the merge information put into a temp table an pulls it from there as follows:

```
OUTPUT $action,DELETED.*,INSERTED.*;
```

Now this works, but it seems adding

```
UPDATED.*
```

does not work. Ideally we would like to get the updated changes in there as well. Is it possible to get all three change actions outputs?

Thank you.

EDIT: I have found after rereading some material I was originally looking for that the answer seems to be here: [Using the Output Clause with T-SQL Merge](http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/06/using-the-output-clause-with-t-sql-merge/)

I will have to do some further testing to get the output I'm looking for but it seems updates should be labeled, unsure why they weren't showing up as such previously.

Comment: why cant u use `update` trigger

Comment: It doesn't seem to output. But also we don't just want updated we want all three.

Comment: did u tried declaring a table and capturing all 3 actions into the table?

Comment: Yes. Only inserted & deleted output.

Comment: Did u check in output table   `where actiontype = 'Update'`

Comment: It is worth of adding insert/Update query for temp tables aswel

Comment: We did check actiontype = 'Update', it doesn't show up. It's going into a permanent table. But we would like to test everything first.

Comment: It could be , there are no updated rows. Try updating  source date for testing purpose and check

Comment: We specifically tested updated rows.